# How to give an image a link in PHP?

Tags: php, html

I need to give these images a link from my db. I have a column in the same table that holds a link, the column is titled "product_url". I am so new to this, that everything I try keeps giving me an error. I want to make the title and the screenshots link to the product url page. Can anyone offer any advice, pls?

```
<div class="app-title"><?=$title?></div>

<span class="app-screenshots">

<?php 
     if (!empty($app['additional_images'])) echo'<span>'.$app['additional_images'].'</span>';
     if (!empty($app['additional_images_2'])) echo '<span>'.$app['additional_images_2'].'</span>';
?>
```

I know I should at least try to provide my own answer, but I can't even do that. I've been trying for days and doing nothing but wasting my time. thank you for any help.

Comment: What is an example value of $app['additional_images'] ? Where is product_url?

Comment: it is bad practice to save the whole URL in database, however show the example of your URL which you are saving in database.

Comment: where is stored the url of the image ? is it `$app['additional_images']` ?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe what you are looking for is :

```
echo '<span><img src="'.$app['additional_images'].'"></span>';
```

(if `$app['additional_images']` is the link to your image file)

---

**EDIT**

If you want the image to link to a specific url, let's say 'myPage.html' :

```
echo '<span><a href="myPage.html"><img src="'.$app['additional_images'].'"></a></span>';
```

Answer (score 0):

As I understand correct you have stored the URL to a picture in the database and not the binary data of the picture. Storing the binary data of a picture and the display it wouldn't make much sense. You would have to copy it to a public folder and generate an URL to use in HTML.
To achieve what you want you could just use simple HTML.

```
<a href="[Link from DB]">
    <img src="[URL of picture]" />
</a>
```

To use it with PHP you just echo the text:

```
<?php
    echo "<a href=\"" . $app['product_url'] . "\">";
    echo "    <img src=\"" . $app['additional_images'] . "\" />";
    echo "</a>";
?>
```

I have not tested this code! There might be syntax errors in it!

Answer (score 0):

did some guessing work,

i guess `$app['additional_images']` is a path to an image, and i guess `$app['product_url']` is a link? if thats the case then try to reconstruct the link to the product and insert the image:

```
$app['additional_images']="https://www.google.com/images/srpr/logo11w.png";
$app['product_url']='<a href="http://www.example.com/product.html">The product</a>';

$temp_arr = explode(">",$app['product_url']);
$reconstruct_link_opening_tag=$temp_arr[0].">";
$reconstruct_link_closing_tag="</a>";

// your code.....

if (!empty($app['additional_images'])) echo'<span>'.$reconstruct_link_opening_tag.'<img src="'.$app['additional_images'].'">'.$reconstruct_link_closing_tag.'</span>';

//  your code....
```

http://3v4l.org/sIDUl

i must say, you need to clean-up your code. dont hold a complete `<a href="....">....</a>` link in your array, just hold the url so its easy to manipulate, like in this case.

if the `$app['product_url']` is just a url (hmm thats kinda obvious how i missed this in my first reading? hmm well you said *I have a column in the same table that holds a link, the column is titled "product_url"*) then this will do:

```
if (!empty($app['additional_images']))
    echo'<span><a href="'.$app['product_url'].'"><img src="'.$app['additional_images'].'"></a></span>';
```